# How to implement integrity control of web applications

Tags: asp.net, security, web

Any web application (for example asp.net/asp.net mvc) contains many *.dll, *.js, *.css, *.aspx, *.ascx, *.cshtml and other files.

We need to implement mechanism to control integrity of all these files to quickly analyze was modified any file or not after deploy.

So, we can on continuous integration server generate file with hashes of all files, put it into some dll of project as embedded resource, and sign dll via strong name. Then in every time we can check integrity of dll and validate hash of all files.

Is there a more simple solution? Or ready to use third party solution?

Comment: Please specify your purpose of doing so. That will give insight into more congenial solution

Comment: This is a security issue, purpose is possibility to quickly check deployed web app has unauthorized modifications or not